# Structural equation software can seemingly do factor analysis with more variables than observations

Tags: r, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

I have discovered that the function umxEFA in the R package umx can do a factor analysis with more variables than observations. A normal factor analysis cannot do this because the covariance matrix becomes singular. The umxEFA function is doing a factor analysis by treating the factors as latent variables in a structural equation model. umxEFA is also very good at handling missing data. The results certainly look right, but are they valid? Of course there is no unique solution, but I assume that it gives a maximum likelihood solution.

There is not much documentation for umxEFA and it does not mention the possibility of having more variables than observations.

BTW, the calculation can take many hours for large data sets, but that is a price I am willing to pay for having such a powerful method.